# Exclude entire group when one condition matches

Tags: sql, group-by

Let's say I have a table like such:

```
Store         productId
Test 1          6524
Test 1          6521
Test 1          6523
Test 2          6234
Test 2          6264
Test 3          6395
```

I am trying to find a way to check whether the store has the product `6524` and if it does it should remove the entire group (store) from the list so that the result can look like the below.

Expected Outcome:

```
Test 2
Test 3
```

I have tried doing a GROUP by followed by HAVING productId <> 6524 but this of course just gets rid of the single row not the entire group.

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: @lemon Amazon Redshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT Store
  FROM tab t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 0 
                      FROM tab 
                     WHERE Store = t.Store
                       AND productId = 6524  )
```

which filters out the matching values of `Store` column

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select store
  from your_table
 group by store
having sum(productId=6524)=0;
```